# Meaning and usage of "lost in the echo"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Recently I was translating few phrases for Google translate in my native language.

I came across a phrase "lost in the echo" . Googling around to find the meaning and usage

of this phrase but no luck .. (many references to Linkin park song :) )

Can anyone explain the same?

Comment: It might be helpful if you could include the entire phrase to provide some context.

Comment: It was like translate "lost in the echo" to Hindi .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His words, however, were ["lost in the echo."](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=CU98tiq4XVoC&pg=PA290&dq=%22lost+in+the+echo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=H-dcVPXHEIGdgwSpq4SABQ&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22lost%20in%20the%20echo%22&f=false)

It means "nobody heard him", "a louder sound muffled his words and they weren't heard" or, simply and metaphorically, "his words were ignored"

Answer (score 3):

Extremely dependent on context. Like any metaphor it has a wide range of connotations. Think "needle in a haystack."

To sight:

> Finding missing persons in New York is like trying to find a needle in a haystack.

To sound:

> Indentifying the out of tune violin in this orchestra's rendition of Pacabel's Canon is like trying to find a needle in a haystack.

And so forth.

"Lost in the echo" is similar, but more subtle:

> Her comments kept reverberating in my mind like a skipping record. Everything that followed was lost in the echo.

Or maybe:

> This Pinot Noir has won awards, some critics citing it's subtle oaky flavoring, but I think it's overly complicated and the lingering berry flavor is strong. The oak is just lost in the echo.

There may not be a literal translation that captures the concept. I'd be interested to know.